# Material-UI Multiline TextField scrolls horizontally

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use Material UI to implement a multiline TextField. Instead of being multi-line the input field is scrolling horizontally. I have replicated the issue in Code Sandbox (link below). It is the **Ad Description** field in **FormItemDetails.js** that I want to be multi-line. I'm grateful for any help! Thanks

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-babbage-ltgtg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

export default function FormItemDetails(props) {
    const { values, handleChange } = props;
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null)
    console.log(values)

    const errorDiv = error 
    ? <div className="error">
        <i class="material-icons error-icon">error_outline</i>
        {error}
      </div> 
    : '';

    useEffect(() => setError(null), []);

    function cont(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const requiredFields = ['title', 'description', 'price']

        for (const key of requiredFields) {
            if (!values[key]) {
                setError(`A ${key} is required`)
                return
            }
        }
        props.nextStep();
    };  

    function back() {
        props.prevStep();
    }


    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <>
            <h2>Enter the advertisement details</h2>
            {errorDiv}
            <TextField 
                required={true}
                fullWidth={true}
                hintText="Enter Your Ad Title"
                floatingLabelText="Ad Title"
                onChange={handleChange('title')}
                defaultValue={values.title}
            />
            <br />
            <TextField 
                required={true}
                fullWidth={true}
                multiline
                hintText="Enter Your Ad Description"
                floatingLabelText="Ad Description"
                onChange={handleChange('description')}
                defaultValue={values.description} 
            />
            <br />
            <TextField 
                required
                fullWidth
                hintText="Enter Your Asking Price"
                floatingLabelText="Price"
                onChange={handleChange('price')}
                defaultValue={values.price}
                
            />
            <br />
            <RaisedButton
                label="Continue"
                primary={true}
                style={styles.button}
                onClick={cont}
            />
            <RaisedButton
                label="Back"
                primary={false}
                style={styles.button}
                onClick={back}
            />
            </>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hello Lydia, please check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/t8dkp and check/try using import '@material-ui/core/TextField' instead "material-ui/TextField".

Let us know.

Comment: Are you intentionally using the [0.20 version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui) of Material-UI instead of the [4.x version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core)?

Comment: Changing to '@material-ui/core/TextField' worked! (I also updated to latest version). I didn't realize I was using an old version. Thank you!

Comment: @marcode_ely can you write your solution as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `material-ui` library used in the project. Actually, you're using `material-ui/TextField` and have to change to `@material-ui/core/TextField` for achieved expected behaviour in the textField. Check this demo [codesandbox.io/s/t8dkp](http://codesandbox.io/s/t8dkp)

Important: Check the last library version as well.